# error "Abort trap: 6" comes when sorting more elements than 15

Tags: c++

i get a error Abort trap:6 when i am sorting more than 15 elements(k>15) in numbers[]. I am using mac os x and code blocks 12.11.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
void getdata(int numbers[],int & k);
void sorting(int numbers[], int & k);

int main()
{
    int numbers[10];
    int k;
    getdata(numbers, k);
    sorting(numbers,k);
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
        cout<<numbers[i]<<" ";

return 0;
}
void getdata(int numbers[],int & k)
{

    cin>>k;
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        cin>>numbers[i];
    }
}
void sorting(int numbers[],int & k)
{
    int j, temp;

    for(int i=1; i<k; i++)
    {
        j=i;
        while(numbers[j]<numbers[j-1] && j>0)
        {
            temp=numbers[j-1];
            numbers[j-1]=numbers[j];
            numbers[j]=temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm, your `numbers` array is only 10 elements long. So it should break at 11 elements already. The fact that it doesn't is pure luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i get a error Abort trap:6 when i am sorting more than 15
>   elements(k>15) in numbers[].

That's because your `numbers[]` only contains 10 elements:

> ```
> int numbers[10];
> ```

Trying to access an array element that does not exist is **undefined behaviour**. Which means that the program is allowed to do everything, including crashing every now and then in various ways including the one you experience, or even producing the expected output if it coincidentally feels like it.

You have to know what you want:

- ***Either*** a collection of `int`s whose size is fixed at compile time and which cannot ever grow or shrink? If so, use [`std::array<int, 10>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and make sure that at most 10 numbers can be entered by the user (e.g. by exiting the program with an error message if a number greater than 10 is entered).
- ***Or*** a collection of `int`s which can grow while the program is running? If so, use [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and `push_back` elements to it as their are entered.

Answer (score 1):

Line 12:

```
    int numbers[10];
```

You are reserving space for only 10 integers. Use a `std::vector<int>` that grows with the input instead. Neither get_data nor your sorting function will then require the k parameter. The vector holds the size.